# Type 'WithId<Document>' is not assignable to type 'OptionalUnlessRequiredId<T>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I have the following interface:

```
export interface IDataAccessLayer<T> {
  ...
  insertOne(data: T): Promise<T> | null;
  ...
}
```

I am trying to implement it like:

```
class MongoDAL<T extends WithId<Document>> implements IDataAccessLayer<T> {
...
  async insertOne(data: T): Promise<T> {
    return this.client
        .db(this.database)
        .collection<T>(this.collection)
        .insertOne(data).then((result) => { // <--- Here I get the type error
            data._id = result.insertedId;
            return data;
        });
  }
...
```

But on the commented line (`.insertOne(data)`) I get a type error:

```
Type 'WithId<Document>' is not assignable to type 'OptionalUnlessRequiredId<T>'.
```

I seem not to understand how to circumvent the error in a reasonable way besides `.insertOne(data as any)`.

Probably relates to [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-4470)